# How can I correctly pre-enhance Mustache templates with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, mustache

I'm trying to speed up my jQuery Mobile and backbone.js based application, especially the part when it is enhancing form elements (and there are many of them). I was thinking I could let jQM "pre-enhance" the form templates and then compile the templating function with enhanced markup instead of having to enhance all the form elements on each page rendering. This worked fine until I implemented checked / unchecked checkboxes. The template basically looks like:

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>{{legend}}</legend>
        {{#items}}
        <label for="{{id}}">{{#name}}{{name}}{{/name}}{{^name}}No name given{{/name}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}" {{#checked}}checked{{/checked}}>
        {{/items}}
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I define my template function in the Backbone-View I am trying to do the following:

```
var preEnhance = $('<div>').hide().html($('#tmpl').html()).appendTo($('body')).trigger('create');
return Mustache.compile(preEnhance.html());
```

I would like to use it against data like this:

```
{legend: 'Pre Enhanced Forms, How?', items:[{id:'a',name:'A', checked: true},{id:'b',name:'B'},{id:'c'}]}
```

Yet, jQuery Mobile does something strange to the `{{#checked}}checked{{/checked}}` part: it is turned into `{{#checked}}checked{{="" checked}}=""` which I guess is due to the `/` that jQM will interpret as the beginning of a closing tag (correct me if I'm wrong). And like this, I cannot render the template anymore.

Can I do something about this? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to use pre-enhanced templates? I wouldn't want to go as far as using enhanced and hard-coded markup in my templates.

There's also a (failing) [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxfGt/) for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just add the checked attribute and the pass the checked value.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}" checked="{{#checked}}{{checked}}{{/checked}}" >
```

I updated the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PxfGt/4/

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the `{{="` but somehow it will have all checkboxes checked, even if I set them explicitly to `false`.

Comment: This is because in HTML 'checked' and 'checked="checked"' both mean that the box should be checked.